# How to make this form take full space on mobile

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap to make my portfolio website and i want to add the newsletter component and it look good on desktop but i can't seem to make it take the whole row on mobile

```
<Col lg={12}>
    <div className="newsletter-bx wow slideInUp">
      <Row>
        <Col lg={12} md={6} xl={5}>
          <h3>Subscribe to our Newsletter<br></br> & Never miss latest updates</h3>
          {status === 'sending' && <Alert>Sending...</Alert>}
          {status === 'error' && <Alert variant="danger">{message}</Alert>}
          {status === 'success' && <Alert variant="success">{message}</Alert>}
        </Col>
        <Col md={6} xl={7}>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="new-email-bx">
              <input value={email} type="email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Email Address" />
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  </Col>
```

This is my code.

[Newsletter component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15k0i.png)

Comment: Please, show css for `newsletter-bx wow slideInUp`.

Comment: wow and slideinup are reduntant I haven't it in the css file but here is the code for newsletter-bx

.newsletter-bx {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 55px;
  color: #121212;
  padding: 85px 125px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  margin-top: -122px;

Comment: There is `padding: 85px 125px;` that's why it doesn't take the whole row.

Comment: should i remove the padding?

Comment: It will look really bad if i remove it